# How can I handle the bad url error using combine?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, combine

I am using combine to handle the network response. I am stuck here to handle the common errors. Can you please help me how Can I handle the errors.

```
func performRequest<T:Decodable>(router:APIConfiguration, decodeType:T.Type) ->AnyPublisher<DataResponse<T, NetworkError>, Never> {
    guard let url = URL.init(string: router.requestedURL) else {
        return Fail(error: NetworkError.init(code: 2345, message: "Bad URL")).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    let storage = KeycheinStorage()
    print(router.requestedURL,router.parameters ?? [:])
    return AF.request(router.requestedURL, method: router.method, parameters: router.parameters, interceptor: AuthTokenInterceptor(storage: storage))
        .validate()
        .publishDecodable(type: T.self)
        .map { response in
            response.mapError { error in
                let networkError = response.data.flatMap {
                    try? JSONDecoder().decode(NetworkError.self, from: $0)
                } ?? NetworkError(error)
                ErrorHandler.default.handle(networkError)
                return networkError
            }
        }
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Either change your function signature or use something like Just instead of Fail

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the method you are building specifies that it never will return an error, but then you try to do exactly that. You are defining `Never` as the failure type in the return types of your method declaration:

`func performRequest<T:Decodable> ...﻿ -> AnyPublisher<DataResponse<T, NetworkError>, Never>`

You can fix that by not using `Never`, but for example `Error` like this:

`func performRequest<T:Decodable> ...﻿ -> AnyPublisher<DataResponse<T, NetworkError>, Error>`

Then you will be able to send any error in the publisher.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Joakim Danielson, you can use `Just` here, you just need to wrap your `NetworkError` in a `DataResponse`. Unfortunately there's no convenient initializer, so you need to be pretty verbose.

```swift
Just(DataResponse<T, NetworkError>(request: nil, 
                                   response: nil, 
                                   data: nil, 
                                   metrics: nil, 
                                   serializationDuration: 0, 
                                   result: .failure(<your error>))
```

However, instead of doing that I suggest you simply adopt Alamofire's `URLRequestConvertible` for your `APIConfiguration` type so Alamofire can handle the URL checking and error production for you.

Additionally, Alamofire's completion handlers and even publishers complete on the main queue by default, so the `receive(on:)` call is unnecessary.